# Join in SpringBoot is returning null but MySQL returns 4 rows

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, join

Sender Entity:

```
@Entity(name="MESSAGES")
public class MessageSender {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer message_id;

    private Integer sender_id;
    private String subject;

    private String body;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "attachment", columnDefinition = "BLOB")
    private byte[] attachment;

    private Timestamp sent_date;
    private Integer parent_message_id;

    private String trigger;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private MessageRecipient message_recipient ;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private TimeTrigger timeTrigger ;

    //getters and setters
    }
}
```

Receiver Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "MESSAGE_RECIPIENT")
public class MessageRecipient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer message_recipient_id;

    private Integer recipient_id;
    private Integer recipient_group_id;
    private Integer message_id;
    private String notification_sent;
    private String is_read;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="message_recipient")
    private MessageSender message_sender;

    //getters and setters
```

Join Code:

```
public interface MessageSenderRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageSender, Integer> {
    @Query("select m.message_id, m.message_recipient from MESSAGES m")
    List<MessageSender> fetchMessagesInnerJoin();
}
```

When I access the API through the controller, the output is empty. However, I know that 4 rows should be returned and when I execute the Join query on MySQL, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the name of your Java classes.`@Query("select m.message_id, m.message_recipient from MessageSender m")`

Comment: That gives me a  ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MessageSender is not mapped [select m.message_id, m.message_recipient from MessageSender m]```

Comment: check if your entity is scanned properly. and also `@Repository` is missing from your repository.

Comment: Added ```@Repository``` but it made no difference. Both entities are being accessed separately but not together. The output from the Sender Repository code: ```{"message_id":1023,"sender_id":32002,"subject":null,"body":"why so serious","attachment":null,"sent_date":null,"parent_message_id":null,"trigger":null,"timeTrigger":null,"messageRecipient":null}```

Comment: There is a response returned by the Receiver Reository though for the same Message ID: ```{"message_recipient_id":2,"recipient_id":10,"recipient_group_id":null,"message_id":1023,"notification_sent":null,"is_read":null,"message_sender":null}``` Why isn't the response null in the previous case?